# Visual Studio Code Breadcrumbs collapse

Tags: visual-studio-code

For the breadcrumbs in Visual Studio Code, is there a way to have it to collapse to functions/methods and not expand down to each section:

[image]

I'd rather have the menu open and only show the top level class methods.  _loadAllTableForBranch would be collapsed.  I don't need to see each `then` block in that method.

Comment: Does the regular collapse button (little down arrow immediately to the left of the expanded method) not do what you need?

Comment: @meg It does collapse that section, but every time I open that, I would need to collapse all the arrows looking for the method I want.  Too tedious to be useful.